# Overlay text on image in header of docx - rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Using r markdown, I need to overlay a string on an existing image in the header of a docx one that is aligned to the bottom right hand corner of the header.

Also, I need to be able to alter the content of the string if possible.

I've got the image using the [reference document approach](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html) suggested by Yihui Xie in the YAML header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Simon"
date: "Thursday, May 21, 2015"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template_image.docx
---
```

[edit] In case it is helpful you can [find template_image.docx here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8l1itipt3otyrr/template-image.docx?dl=0). If anyone could tell me how I could overlay text on that header image using rmarkdown I could appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hard to help. You might want to provide your `template_image.docx`.

Comment: Thanks for that Martin. I have updated the post with a link to the template. Maybe I have misunderstood but I imagine that location of image was unclear from my original post - my fault - hopefully this clears it up.